# How can I send several images through the response object to my front end using MongoDB, GridFs Node.Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I have images linked to a user in a MongoDB collection that I can successfully store and retrieve using multer and GridFS. I am having trouble with finding a way to stream the multiple images through the response header. I have successfully sent one image but cannot send several images at once to my front end.

**Here is my route and my initial attempt:**

```
router.get("/my-projects", async (req, res) => {
  res.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
  const db = mongoose.connections[0].db;

  gfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(db, { bucketName: "uploads" });
  await gfs
    .find({
      metadata: {
        _id: req.user._id,  // Finding collection based off user id
      },
    })
    .toArray((err, files) => { // "files" is in an array type of user images
      if (!files || files.length === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          error: "No files exist",
        });
      }
      for (const file of files) {
        const imageStream = gfs.openDownloadStreamByName(file.filename)
        imageStream.pipe(res);
      }
    });
});
```

Here is where the problem lies. I am essentially piping the first stream that finishes. How can I pipe all images/streams in an array type?

```
for (const file of files) {
        const imageStream = gfs.openDownloadStreamByName(file.filename)
        imageStream.pipe(res);
      }
```

**The Front End:**

```
async function getProjects() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:3001/api/dashboard/my-projects",
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
          },
        }
      );
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      console.log(imageURL); // returns "blob:http://localhost:5173/6b40e4da-a70e-42da-b8c8"
    }
```

The blob that returns and renders to an img tag is one of the three images stored. It seems to render the first image available so it seems random.
I realize that I am not going to get all three images through one download stream but I don't know how to separate the download streams to an array type so I can loop through in the front end.

**Bonus Question:**
Is there an easier way to store and retrieve multiple images using another technology other than MongoDB? Should I split the data between two different Dbs such as firebase for images and mongodb for user info? Am I going *crazy*?

Comment: Is it necessary to store images in a database? Off the top of my head, I would just store these in S3 with a S3 url stored in the database. Then send signed S3 urls over to the frontend.

I'm not sure what the most common method for this is though...

Comment: @TaeHyungKim I figured I would probably have to use something separate from mongodb to store images. Im still fairly new to node.js and databases in general so I figure I can just throw everything in the same db. Thanks for your response.